# Isn't foreign key to contenttype sufficient?

Tags: django, content-type

In Django, we have ContentType model.
Consider I have models A, B and C.

```
class A(models.Model):
  field1 = models.BooleanField(default=True)
  c = models.OneToOneField(myapp.C)

class B(models.Model):
  field2 = models.CharField()

class C(models.Model):
  limits = models.Q(app_label=u'students', model=u'a') | \
             models.Q(app_label=u'myapp', model=u'b')
  content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, limit_choices_to=limits)
```

Now if I have an object of C say c1 with content_type a, I can access `c1.a` or `c1.a.field1` if there exist an object of A which refers to c1.
So, why do I need `GenericForeignKey` if I can access `a` through `c1`.

Also what if I call, c2.b.field2 if c2 is an object of C with content_type as B?

Comment: You should choose between a `OneToOneField` from `A` to `C` and a `GenericForeignKey` on `C`. Having both is redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by knbk, we should choose between OneToOneField from A to C and a GenericForeignKey on C. Having both is redundant. A generic relation can be used in model A and B to enable reverse querying.